# What is (or where can i find) the algorithm to decode FLAC to PCM?

Tags: c#, algorithms, compression

I'm trying to program a very basic FLAC player using 100% C# completely from scratch. My understanding of this type of thing is very limited, so I'm using this project as a way to learn about compression and decompression. I'm a computer science and math major currently in university, so I'm not adverse to learning whatever math may be involved.

I've looked up the format specifications on xiph.org and I understand how the headers and all are structured, but I can't seem to find a concise explanation of how the audio compression works. How do I go about converting the frames to pcm?

Sadly,  my knowledge of C/C++ is extremely limited, as I only have experience with Java and C#. As such, trying to navigate the c++ code already out there is not a great starting point. I looked at FlacBox and learned quite a bit from it, but it's barely commented at all and I am lost trying to figure out how the conversion from flac to pcm works.

So what should I read as far as math goes so I can get started with this? Where can I find a basic algorithm for converting the audio frames to wav? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to look a little closer at the [format](http://xiph.org/flac/format.html) page on the FLAC website.  The ["prediction" paragraph](http://xiph.org/flac/format.html#prediction) leads to [this article](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/1999/HPL-1999-144.pdf), which describes the AudioPak algorithm in detail, and also [Shorten](http://svr-www.eng.cam.ac.uk/reports/abstracts/robinson_tr156.html).

You should learn and understand these algorithms and the associated math before digging into the source code.  That might take awhile.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to those documents. I don't mind it taking a while, as long as I can get all the information I need to **decode** a stream, as opposed to just encoding one.